# Скорость тестирования нового кода, spring, intelij ide, glassfish

Tags: spring, glassfish, java, тестирование, intellij-idea

Как увеличить скорость тестирования нового кода на технологиях ?
spring, intelij ide, glassfish

т.е. добавив новый код в контроллер или шаблон, чтобы протестировать результат нужно 
заново задеплоить приложенение на тестовый сервер.

В intellij idea это следующий набор действий Run->Run 'GlassFish 4.0.0'->Redeploy.

По времени это занимает 30-60 секунд.
Т.е. если какой то код не корректно работает то тестирование занимает много времени.

Answer (score 4):

Для этого есть платный и недешевый продукт [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). Я его не рекламирую, просто на рынке у него практически нет конкурентов и он действительно ровно под это затачивался. Можете попробовать триальную версию. (Я пробовал, ничего не вышло, слишком долго разбираться не стал.)

Совсем недавно появился проект [Spring Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) тоже нацелен на патченье JVM без полного рестарта. Бесплатный и open source от разработчиков Spring. У меня он на проекте с Spring-Data-Jpa нормально не заработал, возможно, что на других проектах он будет работать лучше.

Есть ещё вариант попробовать писать тесты: юнит (или интеграционные), тогда так часто не нужно будет перезапускать всё приложение, вместо этого вы будете тестировать только конкретный компонент и запускать тесты только для этого компонента.

Для JSP страниц, кстати, можно настроить application server, чтобы он их каждый раз компилировал заново, это позволит менять их в редакторе, сохранять и после обновления страницы вы будете видеть ваши изменения.

Также некоторые application server-а поддерживают hot update (или как-то так он называется). Как минимум, это умеет делать WildFly (бывший JBoss AS). Нужно только его настроить и сконфигурировать вашу IDE (в IDEA точно работает).

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать более легковесный веб-сервер, тот же Tomcat или Jetty. В IDEA в debug режиме работает Hot Swap классов (если структура класса не меняется, а меняется только код методов).